# How to extract specific segments from powerline?

Tags: tmux, powerline

Powerline (https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) is a generic installation for powerlines for shells, vim, tmux, etc. Once installed including the following the tmux config will generate the right side of the status line in the tmux:

```
powerline tmux right
```

However, this is cluttered with a lot of information, so ideally I only want to extract specific segments using powerline to include in tmux status line.

For example, instead of using:

```
set -g status-right '#(powerline tmux right)'
```

If I was interested in 'uptime', 'datetime', and 'cpu', I would want use, say:

```
set -g status-right '#(powerline tmux right uptime,datetime,cpu)'
```

PS: I am unable to create a new tag 'powerline', and 'vim-powerline' is not the same as this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify your config file in order to add or remove segments as explained here: https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#quick-setup-guide

You don't need to fiddle with tmuy settings only once to tell tmux to use Powerline. Once tmux picks it up for its status bar you only need to adapt the Powerline config file to your needs. You might want to search github for examples. It's a bit of a nuisance to find out how it works for all the different segments or for additional ones.